# Financial Aid Tag?

Tags: feature-request

This [recent post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31096/heavy-financial-aid-question) is pretty short on tags, and the one it has really isn't that great for it, so I was hoping to add a `financial-aid` tag since I felt like it is relevant, at the very least, to academia, and several other questions on this site. I was surprised to find it didn't exist and have gone ahead and placed it into the edit queue.

[These are the questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=financial+aid) that show up for a search of financial aid.

Some of the questions only touch on the issue as, i.e., part of an enrollment decision, but others appear to rely heavily on approaches regarding the handling of financial aid.

A downside for the tag is that some people may see the tag and attempt to use it for "Please help me find scholarships I qualify for", but to be honest, those questions have been asked before without the tag in existence.

Is this tag relevant and helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [funding](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/funding) tag includes financial aid. Its excerpt is:

> This tag refers to questions related to source and utilization of academic funding from government or non-governmental sources.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Would financial-aid qualify for a tag synonym then? It currently has grants, scholarships, and fellowships.